# ckeditor limited enabling of tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, editor, ckeditor

How do I disable some tags in ckeditor while allowing some other tags. For eg: I want to disable div tags but want to allow image tags. I am using as below. If I disable the allowedContent using //, then the full editor shows up. I want to allow most tags including font-color, font-name, font-size, images but want to disable div.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( "xeditor", {
allowedContent: {'img[!src] a[!href] b i u s sup sub ul ol li p[*] table tbody tr td h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 hr pre': true},} );
```

If I uncomment the allowedContent filter above it stops unwanted tags but I can't seem to let images/font-* to showup!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Link](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config)   Include div in this

```
     CKEDITOR.config.removeFormatTags = 'b,big,code,del,dfn,em,font,i,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,span,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,u,var';
```

or

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'p(*){*}[*]';
```

Comment: I added  CKEDITOR.replace( "mxmesg", {removePlugins: 'forms,flash',
     removeFormatTags: 'div',} ); Now it disabled the forms and flash which is the main thing for me. I still get the div container button though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is the toolbar, you can just edit it directly, there is a config option for that; see http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar

Although I would also keep editing that ACF configuration to find why images and fonts don't work. As for the images, I think you need to give it a little more room to work than just `img[!src]`. As for the fonts, you are not allowing `span`, that might disable the font styles. The styles like spans a lot. Here's an edited version very similar to what I use, edited to fit your situation a little better.

```
// No other tags are allowed the ones defined.
// http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules-section-3
// [*] allows all attributes
// (*) allows all classes
// {*} allows all styles
CKEDITOR.replace('textarea_id', {
    allowedContent: 
        // Allow these without any style, class or attribute
        'b i u s sup sub ul ol li tr td h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 hr pre; ' +

        // Allow any attribute and certain styles for TD and TH
        'td th [*]{width,height,text-align,vertical-align,white-space,border-color,background-color}; ' +

        // Allow any attribute but only height and width style for table
        'table [*]{height, width};' + 

        // Allow any attribute and style - this is a little too loose
        'p span img a tr thead tbody a caption *[*]{*}; ' + 

        // Allow any class for any element
        '*(*)' 
});
```

I don't recommend simply just copying it from here, but rather trying to understand it and choose the correct tags for you. The important bit I think is to add more freedom for IMG and adding SPAN, but if you Grok the ACF it'll help working with CKEditor in the future.

Comment: You could optimize that rule set a lot and it's very loose, but the point isn't to provide a ready solution, the point is that ACF is flexible, highly configurable and ultra-awesome.

Comment: That is a very detailed example to build on. I will try this one. However I am using CKEDITOR.replace( "mxmesg", {removePlugins: 'forms,flash', removeFormatTags: 'div',} ); and this is clearing up the forms and flash. I will try to experiment with your example as well. Thanks

Comment: @user2530027 if that works for you, then great, go with that :)

Comment: see it at http://rue16.com - if you open any thread and hit reply it is doing what I was trying to do. However it still allows div though. For now I will let div be. I wonder if I should just string replace each div.. with p-span ? Thanks

Comment: I'll check it out. You could try `removePlugins: 'forms,flash,div'` as well if you have no need for divs, I don't know if it has sideaffects but at least it could work.